# how to set setting file when file download by django+nginx+uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, setting

I wrote the file download code using the django + nginx + uwsgi

following is my code

```
def download_latest_db(request):
    latest_db = DB.objects.all().first()
    chunk_size = 8192
    if latest_db is not None:
        response = FileResponse(FileWrapper(open(latest_db.locate, 'rb'), chunk_size))
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(latest_db .locate)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s.db"'% latest_db.version
        return response
    return Response(status=404)
```

but file download almost failed when i try five times
and it doesn't occur in runserver mode

i guess it's problem with nginx setting.
please help me

following is my nginx settings. i use base setting

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#       # See sample authentication script at:
#       # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#       # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#       # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#       # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:110;
#               protocol   pop3;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#
#       server {
#               listen     localhost:143;
#               protocol   imap;
#               proxy      on;
#       }
#}
```

should i add other options?

Comment: If you think that there is a problem with your nginx settings, you should post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to bump your nginx `client_max_body_size` setting.  The default is 1MB which is probably too small for a view named 'download_latest_db'  =D

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size

Comment: thank you! i solved the problem. I wrong know that client_max_body_size is set only one response body size.